# Ignore certain subdirectories using os.walk() [Python]

Tags: python, os.walk

I have the following function currently:

```
def create_image_list(directory):

    extensions = ('.jpg', 'jpeg', '.png', '.bmp')
    file_list = []

    for root, directories, files in os.walk(directory):
        for filename in files:
            if filename.endswith(extensions):
                filepath = os.path.join(root, filename)
                file_list.append(filepath)
```

Which goes through every file and subdirectory in a given directory and puts the full path to any files with the given extensions in the list. However, I would like to ignore certain subdirectories, such as those labelled `thumbs`. How would I go about this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can filter your `directories` object inside the `for` loop. To quote the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.walk)

> When topdown is True, the caller can modify the dirnames list in-place
>   (perhaps using del or slice assignment), and walk() will only recurse
>   into the subdirectories whose names remain in dirnames; this can be
>   used to prune the search, impose a specific order of visiting, or even
>   to inform walk() about directories the caller creates or renames
>   before it resumes walk() again.

So something like

```
for root, directories, files in os.walk(directory):
    directories[:] = [d for d in directories if d not in ['thumbs']]
    for filename in files:
        if filename.endswith(extensions):
            filepath = os.path.join(root, filename)
            file_list.append(filepath)
```

To ignore other directories, you would add their names to the `['thumbs']` list.